# Applying Stoke's theorem.

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been pulling my hair on this question for a while,

> Let $i_j : \Bbb R^{n-1} \to \Bbb R^{n}$ with $1 \leq j \leq n$ be defined by $$i_j(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) = (x_1,\dots,0_j,\dots,x_{n-1})$$ where we noted that the $j$th element is $0$. Prove that $$\int_{\Bbb R^{n}_{+}} d\omega = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j \int_{\Bbb R^{n-1}_{+}} i^*_j(\omega)$$ where $\Bbb R^{n}_{+} = \{x \in \Bbb R^n: x_i \geq 0, 1\leq i \leq n\}$, $\omega$ is a smooth $n-1$ differential form on $\Bbb{R}^n$ with $supp(\omega)\cap R^{n}_{+}$ compact.

So here are my ideas, I know the $i_j$ map "looks like" the inclusion/identity map here, so something tells me I need to use that in my proof (because otherwise we can't define $i_j^*$, the pullback).

Here is what I came up with,

$$\omega|_{\partial \Bbb R^{n}_{+}} = f_1(0,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_2 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n$$ with $supp f_i \subset \Bbb R^{n}_{+}$

Hence, $$\int_{\partial \Bbb R^{n}_{+}  }\omega = \int f_1(0,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_2 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n$$ and we also get I get $\int_{\Bbb R^{n}_{+}} d\omega = \sum_{i =1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1}\int_{\Bbb R^{n}_{+}} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}dx_2 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_n$. Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you explain what is that $i$ in the definition of $\mathbb R^n_+$ and is it $\partial R^n_+$ in the RHS of the equality?

Comment: @John, it's a typo, it's supposed to be an $i$. Actually there are several typos…let me fix, thanks for that.

Comment: @John, it is supposed to be the half-space but with one dimension down, not the boundary.

Comment: Do you want to apply Stokes's theorem to prove this? (But it seems to me that it is part of the steps in the proof of Stokes theorem (to manifolds with corners))

Comment: @John, are the steps not the same…? My current work mimics the proof of the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your definition, $\omega$ can be written as

$$\omega = \sum_{j=1}^n f_j dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{dx^j} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n, $$

where $\hat{dx^j}$ means that we remove that $dx^j$ and $f_i$ are functions with compact support. Thus

$$d\omega = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1}\frac{\partial f_j }{\partial x^j} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$$

Then

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n_+} dw = \sum_{j=1}^n \int_0^ d\cdots \int_0^d (-1)^{j-1}\frac{\partial f_j }{\partial x^j} dx^1 \cdots dx^n$$

where we suppose that the support of $f_j$'s are in $[0,d] \times \cdots \times [0,d]$. Fixing each $j$,

$$\int_0^ d\cdots \int_0^d (-1)^{j-1}\frac{\partial f_j }{\partial x^j} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n $$
$$ =  (-1)^{j-1}\int_0^ d\cdots \int_0^d \bigg(\int_0^d \frac{\partial f_i }{\partial x^i} dx^i\bigg) dx^1 \cdots \hat{dx^i} \cdots  dx^n$$

$$= (-1)^{j}\int_0^ d\cdots \int_0^d f_i(x^1, \cdots, 0, \cdots , x^n)dx^1 \cdots \hat{dx^i} \cdots  dx^n$$

$$= (-1)^{j}\int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}_+} i_j^*\omega $$

where we use the fundamental theorem of calculus in the second equality and

$$i_j^* \omega = f(i_j(x)) dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n. $$

Comment: this mimics John Lee's proof (not your name lol).